# 'Meta' relation within Python classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to create two classes in the following way:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, n):

        self.Bs = [B(i,self) for i in range(n)]

class B:

    def __init__(self, i, a):

        self.i = i
        self.a = a

        print(a.Bs) # this line throws an error
```

When I take the *print* statement out, everything goes fine:

```
a = A(2)

a.Bs

→ [<__main__.B at 0x10d45c0d0>, <__main__.B at 0x10d45c490>]


(a.Bs[0].a == a) & (a.Bs[1].a == a)

→ True
```

The problem happens when I try to access the .Bs attribute of A within the constructor of class B (such as in the *print* statement).

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that the list-comprehension in `A.__init__` isn't done yet by the time you first `print(a.Bs)` in `B.__init__`.

Comment: I turned the list-comprehension into a normal *for loop* and it worked out !

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an "infinite loop", exactly. This isn't exactly unexpected behavior to be honest. `a.Bs` does not exist when you call `print(a.Bs)` in `B.__init__` because you are invoking the `B.__init__` method as part of the list-comprehension in `A.__init__`. The list object generated by the list-comprehension will not be bound to the variable `Bs` until the entire list-comprehension has been evaluated. As an alternative you could turn your list-comprehension into a generator so that the `B` objects inside it are created and evaluated lazily.

Comment: @Davichete that was one of my attempts, but it still gave the same error. The problem was on using the list-comprehension syntax.

Comment: @user10987432 you answered my question in you comments, would post an answer (showing how to turn the list-comprehension into a generator) so I could choose yours as accepted? (@quadcodas thanks for you reply, I upvoted it ;) )

Comment: Sure, if that's helpful! Just a minute.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, I just realized that turning `Bs` into a generator wouldn't be exactly equivalent. It would deviate too much from your original intention I think, in which case I would just go with the for-loop solution. With a generator, doing `print(a.Bs)` would just print the generator object, and not the individual B objects as they are being generated. Sorry about that!

Comment: That’s fine! Anyway thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user10987432 pointed out, by the time you try to `print(a.Bs)`, `a.Bs` doesn't exist yet. Python first has to evaluate the list comprehension on the right side, then assign it to the variable on the left side. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this helps? In `A.__init__`, do:

```
def __init__(self, n):
    self.Bs = []
    for i in range(n):
        self.Bs.append(B(i,self))
```

That way, `a.Bs` does exist from the beginning and is being altered as all the `Bs` are created:

```
>>> a = A(4)
[]
[<__main__.B object at 0x7f690b281518>]
[<__main__.B object at 0x7f690b281518>, <__main__.B object at 0x7f690b281550>]
[<__main__.B object at 0x7f690b281518>, <__main__.B object at 0x7f690b281550>, <__main__.B object at 0x7f690b281588>]
```

Note how the print is evoked each time that a `B.__init__` is called and how the list grows as more `Bs` are created